How can I arrange as many words as possible in a row dynamically with SwiftUI?
I have a question about Swift UI.
As shown in the picture, each word is arranged in the rows, which is good. But the number of words for each row is static (four words for each row for now) and there are some space left if those words are short.
How can I fix the problem?? Thanks in advance.

 let itemsPerRow = 4
             ScrollView {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        let minNumLines = 2
                        let nLines = max(minNumLines, (viewModel.arrangedWords.count + itemsPerRow - 1) / itemsPerRow)
                        ForEach(0..<nLines, id: \.self) { row in
                            HStack(spacing: 5) {
                                ForEach(0..<itemsPerRow, id: \.self) { column in
                                    let index = row * itemsPerRow + column
                                    ZStack {
                                        if index < viewModel.arrangedWords.count {
                                            let targetWord = viewModel.arrangedWords[index]
                                            Text(targetWord)
                                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                                .padding()
                                                .background(Rectangle().fill(Color.green.opacity(0.8)))
                                                .cornerRadius(10)
                                                .onTapGesture {
                                                    viewModel.moveWordOutOfSpace(index: index)
                                                    print("arranged words: \(viewModel.arrangedWords)")
                                                }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    .frame(height: 60)
                                }
                            }
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                            .background(Color.blue)
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .padding(10)
                }


You might just want to use this library instead of writing your own layout.

Google “flow layout”

flow layout worked! Thank you!

ZStack {
                                    if index < viewModel.arrangedWords.count {
                                        let targetWord = viewModel.arrangedWords[index]
                                        HStack{
                                            Spacer()
                                            Text(targetWord)
                                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                                .padding()
                                                .background(Rectangle().fill(Color.green.opacity(0.8)))
                                                .cornerRadius(10)
                                                .onTapGesture {
                                                    viewModel.moveWordOutOfSpace(index: index)
                                                    print("arranged words: \(viewModel.arrangedWords)")
                                                }
                                            Spacer()
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                .frame(height: 60)

You can use this way to consume extra spaces.
